# AngularJS: format of ngClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I'm learning AngularJS and I see the tag "li" is associated with the ngClass directive which has as "{marked: nav.estoy ( '/')}" values. **My question is why the value inside the brackets has the form x: y.** I am that "nav.estoy ('/') is defined in the controller method but do not understand why the response of this method is to":"

```
<body ng-app="app">
<nav ng-controller="navCtrl as nav">
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{marcado: nav.estoy('/')}">
            <a href="#/">Datos personales</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-class can take an object as an argument: [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

the keys of the object are the class names to apply, and the values of the object are expressions that will evaluate truthy or falsey.  in this case it's saying that the class `marcado` will be applied if `nav.estoy('/')` returns true, but it could easily have several keys with several classes to be applied if the values evaluate truthy (non-zero, non-null).

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In the x:y format, x is the class name and y is the expression. I believe they use this name value pair technique so multiple classes can be easily set using commas. Expressions must return a boolean value.

```
    <li ng-class="{marcado: nav.estoy('/'), 'another-class': expression}">
        <a href="#/">Datos personales</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if `nav.estoy('/)` returns a truthy value, then the class "marcado" will be added to the `class` attribute.

From the docs:

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass